# Is there a way to make sure a function runs only once even if multiple user access my web app in python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, flask, web-applications

This is the function which I'll call. This function will create a directory in the server but I want the directories to be created only once. The function should execute only once when the first user visits it.

```
def makedirectories():
        # get list of all the stations and make directories of their name to store files
        ftp = FTP("14.139.107.169")
        ftp.login("ABC", "123456")  # login to FTP account
        print("Successfully logged in")
        ftp.cwd("UKGAWS")  # change working directory to \public_html\
        filenames = ftp.nlst()  # create variable to store contents of \public_html\
        # print(filenames)
        stationList = []
        homeDir = os.getcwd()
        todayDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '%s' % filenames[10][8:14])
        if not (os.path.exists(todayDir)):
            os.makedirs(todayDir)
        os.chdir(todayDir)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of:

1. Function Bound Variable:

```
def makedirectories():
       if not makedirectories.run:
           # your method logic here
       makedirectories.run = True

makedirectories.run = False
```

2. File based solution:
   This is a solution that will work even when you restart the server.

```
def makedirectories():
    if os.path.exists('temp'):
        return # file already exists.
    with open('temp', 'w'):
        pass
    # your logic here
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, @rishabh-bhatnagar. The second option is a good way around. I'll try to implement it.